# Hibernate and angular 4+ http get - Parameter value did not match expected type

Tags: angular, hibernate, http-get, angular-httpclient

I'm experiencing very weird behaviour in my back-end.

On my front-end, which is written in angular 4, I'm calling method from back-end that will acquire all employees for specific organization unit from specific database table. Also, I'm calling method that fills MatSelect with options from back-end app.

CODE:

Back-end Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/orgid/{orgid}", produces = "application/json")
public Iterable<Employee> getEmployeeByOrgId(@PathVariable("orgid") String orgid, HttpServletRequest req){
    Iterable<Employee> getEmpByOrgId = eDao.findEmployeesByOrgNameId(orgid);
        return  getEmpByOrgId;
    }
```

Back-end DAO:

```
  @Query("SELECT new model.Employees(p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName, p.organizationName, p.subOrganizationName, p.mobilephoneNumber, p.telephoneNumber, p.smallImage, p.jobTitle) FROM Employee p WHERE p.orgId = :orgId ORDER by p.lastName")
public Iterable<Employee> findEmployeesByOrgNameId(@Param("orgId") String orgId);
```

Front-end Service:

```
  fetchEmployeesByOrg(org): Observable<Employees[]>{
const url ="employees/orgid/"+org;
return this.http.get<Employees[]>(url);
```

}

Front-end Component:

```
  fetchAllEmployeesByOrgId(org){
this.orgId = org.id.toString();
console.log(typeof this.orgId);
   this.fetch.fetchEmployeesByOrg(this.orgId).subscribe(res => {
      this.EmployeesByOrg = res;
      console.log(this.EmployeesByOrg);
    })
  }
```

Front-end html:

```
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose it">
<mat-option *ngFor="let org of this.orgUnits" [value]="org.value" (click)="fetchAllEmployeesByOrgId(org)">
  {{ org.orgName }}
</mat-option>
```

How my url looks when I click on specific option: `employees/orgid/166`

Problem:

I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [166] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]`
As mentioned above, I'm expecting string in back-end and also, I'm providing string within url.

Maybe it's problem inside of custom query or something?
Any help would be great.

Comment: what is the type of the the culomn orgId in Employee table ??

Comment: it's a number. i'm a bit confused, 'cause in angular 1.x it works with string passing...

Comment: the @param arg must be an integer : `findEmployeesByOrgNameId(@Param("orgId") Integer orgId)` , and in your controller you can parse the value to integer : `eDao.findEmployeesByOrgNameId(Integer.valueOf(orgid));`

Comment: yep, it worked. Post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `@param` arg is injected as a `String` into the query, so the method signature must be changed :

```
findEmployeesByOrgNameId(@Param("orgId") Integer orgId)
```

and if you passe a `String` to you controller (that you are sure is parsable to `Integer`) you can convert the param to an `Integer` then call the dao method :

```
eDao.findEmployeesByOrgNameId(Integer.valueOf(orgid));
```